# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE onActivityResult has empty intent with empty data

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera, onactivityresult

After reading this documentation https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics I want to take a photo and to store the uri of the photo into a given variable. The problem is that I'm storing the variable name and the uri into the intent with `takePictureIntent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_VARNAME, variable)` and `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)`, but in onActivityResult the intent data is empty, and neither the variable and the uri stored are empty. I need to know the uri and the variable. What am I doing wrong?

I need to pass the information as intent data because the class which is firing the action of displaying the camera is differente from the activity class.

class with the action:

```
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_VARNAME, variable);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(), SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().getPackageName(), photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

my activity which receives the result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if( requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        String varName;
        String path;

        if(intent != null) {
            varName = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_VARNAME);
            path = Util.getRealPathFromURI(SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(), intent.getData());
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onActivityResult-> varName: "+varName+" path: "+path);
            if (varName != null && path != null) {
                VariableManager.put(varName, path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

manifest, permission write_external_storage and this code:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

file_paths.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have `photoURI` which you send with `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` so You can simply use it . Save `photoURI` as globally and directly use it . See if `RESULT_OK` is emitted then it means picture was clicked and it will be saved at the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` location.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if( requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        // USe photoURi here
    }
}
```

You can not expect some custom key which is `Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_VARNAME` will be return with System camera Intent. I do not have any knowledge of such thing. 
If you specified `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`  the image taken will be written to that path, and no data will given to `onActivityResult` so you need to persist the file path. 
**PS** : You can save it globally and also make sure you should persist it during `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: What do you mean with "You can not expect some custom key which is Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_VARNAME will be return with System camera Intent. I do not have any knowledge of such thing" ? Do you mean that the intent will be allways empty? why?

Comment: Yeah . With `EXTRA_OUTPUT` it will . It may contain some arbitrary info. But i can not find any documented key which it will return as `URI`. The data you passed to `Intent` will not returned back as it was. So you need to hold it globally.

Comment: what the f.... and this is the best way to proceed if you need the full image and to pass data? really?

Comment: Yeah. If you specified `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` the image taken will be written to that path, and no data will given to `onActivityResult`.

Comment: ADM but there is another way to get the full image without specifying the path in EXTRA_OUTPUT?

Comment: NO for full image this is the recommended way and standard . You see In android we have hundreds of camera app available and if they do not follow same standard  i.e. `EXTRA_OUTPUT`  then the camera intent will be fail . So its the standard most of camera apps follow . If this answer helped you please accept the answer. Thx